# Solving Sudoku purely by logic: why does this X-cycle choose this cell?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

I've been reading several articles on difficult Sudoku puzzles and whether "guessing" is ever acceptable.  The attached image shows the stage I reached using only deduction but at this point I could not see a purely logical correct next step.  I eventually found the solution by "brute force" choosing one number from a pair and proceeding from there. (My first choice was the wrong one of course).

After posting this question I was introduced to a Sudoku solver, a fascinating insight into strategies I have never considered before. I could follow everything although whether I could manage it with just pen and paper is another matter. The only problem I have is at the step which requires use of the X-CYCLE. I cannot see how you decide that C9 is where we should try 4 as the potential solution. Once chosen I can see how the strategy works but why choose 4 in that Cell over 4 in any other cell?

[image: A sudoku grid with theoretical numbers written on it]

Comment: @JLee I used that solver just now (with the original numbers, not the handwritten numbers) and it came back with "Very Hard Grade
Overall Score: 251". Perhaps you entered a number wrong?

Comment: According to [this solver](https://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku.htm) "**Tough Grade**
Overall Score: 137
Comment: This puzzle could require strategies beyond its grade
Note: a partially completed puzzle will have an easier grade than the original puzzle. Grading is most accurate if the number of clues is less than 30.

Comment: @IanMacDonald yep i did. Corrected now. I entered the numbers found so far, so that explains the difference between mine and yours. Does [this solve path](https://www.sudokuwiki.org/sudoku/solvepaths/sp1067160713.htm) help?

Comment: Thank you for all your comments.  The Solver is a fascinating insight into strategies I have never considered before.  I could follow everythung although whether I could manage it with just pen and paper is another matter.  The only problem I have is at the step which requires use of the X-CYCLE.  I cannot see how you decide that C9 is where we should try 4 as the potential solution.  Once chosen I can see how the strategy works but why choose 4 in that Cell over 4 in any other cell?

Comment: @PaulFisher edit that comment/question into your question. Maybe someone well-versed in sudoku strategies will answer.

Comment: @PaulFisher please edit into your question the board right before the X-cycle step, to make your question more self-contained

Answer (score 2):

For me, this one is easier to see if I start with simple alternation elsewhere.

Let's consider all the squares where 4 is still a possibility: [image: sudoku board with remaining possible 4s highlighted]

I can see that there are a number of rows and columns where I have 2 choices for where to put the 4, meaning I have a strong correlation there. For example if Row 3 Column 4 is NOT 4, then Row 9 Column for MUST be, and vice versa.

I'm going to choose red and yellow to color my squares. These do not (yet) correlate to making a choice about whether or not a particular square holds a 4, it just says that whatever is correct for that square, its partner must have the opposite. [image: sudoku board with some squares highlighted either red or yellow]

These are the only strongly linked pairs definite in this chain, but I can see that there is another chain possible, I'm going to color those orange and purple [image: sudoku board with squares highlighted in red, yellow, orange, and purple]

Now I can start thinking about which squares are at the intersection of these chains, in particular, I notice these guys [image: sudoku board with colored arrows pointing at specific squares]
(the other intersections are either already solved, or not candidates for 4)

The square at the purple/ yellow intersection has too many inputs to be an easy check for if/then statements, but the red/orange intersection contributes a single input to each chain, so that's a good place to start checking.

Since it is at the intersection of 2 chains with strong connections on candidates of 4, I should first check to see if it can be 4. When I propagate that through the chains I have identified, I see that I get a contradiction.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation.  It does make sense so I'll try to remember in future!